# If the melting point of Oxygen is -218 Celcius and the melting point of Hydrogen is -259 Celsius, why is the melting point of water 0 Celcius?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, molecules

Forgive my ignorance, but my knowledge of Physics is not much, I am not even a High Schooler yet.

So, out of curiosity, I thought if water is H2O, 2 Hydrogen, and 1 Oxygen, then why is water's melting point not as low as Hydrogen or Oxygen or something in between the melting point of both? After all, water is a combination of both's atoms.

Please explain your answer so that it can be understood by a secondary schooler if possible.

Comment: please read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_point#Predicting_the_melting_point_of_substances_(Lindemann's_criterion)

Comment: @annav Alrighty

Comment: See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond#Water).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all to do with the interaction between the molecules.
The stronger is the bond between molecules the harder it is to separate them and so the higher is the melting/boiling point.
Hydrogen and oxygen molecules can only interact via a comparatively weak [Van der Waals force](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Intermolecular_Forces/Van_der_Waals_Forces) whereas when a water molecule is formed a [dipole moment](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Dipole_Moments) is formed and so the main interactive force is the [hydrogen bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond) which is much stronger the the VdW force.

Comment: Even though all the other answer makes everything clear, and are very detailed. This by far is the one that would easily make the most sense to a secondary schooler. I am gonna accept this :) thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

As you are just beginning to think of physical quantities, the main answer is that , it is that  solids are not a simple aggregate of the atoms that compose them. To become a solid a quantum mechanical binding into a lattice occurs, and that is different for different solids, and will behave differently with the rise of temperature and pressure.

Here is an attempt

> [An attempt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_point#Predicting_the_melting_point_of_substances_(Lindemann%27s_criterion)) to predict the bulk melting point of crystalline materials was first made in 1910 by Frederick Lindemann.The idea behind the theory was the observation that the average amplitude of thermal vibrations increases with increasing temperature. Melting initiates when the amplitude of vibration becomes large enough for adjacent atoms to partly occupy the same space. The Lindemann criterion states that melting is expected when the vibration root mean square amplitude exceeds a threshold value.

So the combination of oxygen and hydrogen into a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_energy) is a different phase of matter than just how oxygen and hydrogen independently behave  with temperature and pressure. It is due to the quantum mechanical interactions binding solids.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Haven't studied lattice energy yet but this seems interesting. I'll read the Wikipedia article and wait for a few more answers, then I'll accept one of them.

Answer (score 4):

The original physical properties of the chemical elements that are joined together into *molecules* will be completely different from those of the molecule thus formed. So for example sodium is a soft, violently reactive shiny metal and chlorine is a pale yellow, violently reactive gas, but their reaction product (sodium chloride) is, of all things, a transparent solid that readily dissolves in water.

You will find out more about this sort of thing in any introductory textbook about *chemistry*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am still waiting if any new answers come.